# Ubuntu login loop 16.04 Error after reinstalling lightdm

Tags: 16.04, login, lightdm, gdm

After getting Ubuntu login loop on Ubuntu 16.04 and following the online tutorial from [here](https://www.computersnyou.com/4947/how-to-solve-ubuntu-login-loop-quick-tip/), I reinstalled lightdm successfully and after reboot, I got this error. It repeats over and over again. The login page does not even load. I am wondering if anybody has seen this before:

[image: Picture of the error]

Comment: So did you reinstall lightdm or gdm? From what I understand, they're incompatible.

Comment: I reinstall lightdm with `sudo apt-get purge lightdm && sudo apt-get install lightdm` and i got this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the invidia driver, the solution was to reinstall the nvidia driver.

```
Sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
Sudo apt-get install nvidia-*** (***= is the version of the nvidia)
```